# Question about equilibrium points of autonomous ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My professor stated that if $x' = f(x)$ (so it is autonomous), then the equilibrium points are the set of $x_{eq}$ such that $f(x_{eq}) = 0$. Although this makes intuitive sense, I believe that this statement is not perfectly true. For example, consider $x ' = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$. There are infinitely many solutions, one of which is $x(t) = \left(\frac{2}{3}t\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$. We have there that $f(0) = 0$, yet $0$ is not an equilibrium point of $x(t)$ since $x(0)\neq x(1)$. Is there a condition I am missing for this condition to classify equilibrium points, or am I misunderstanding equilibrium points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the definition of a stationary or equilibrium point, to be a root of the right side. The constant function with that point as value is a solution. This does not include stability or uniqueness properties, these are additional.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but stability seems to be focused on the behavior of solutions with initial conditions near the equilibrium point. My issue is that I don't see $0$ as an equilibrium point for the solution $x(t) = \left(\frac{2}{3}t\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$. Does this mean that equilibrium points only exist for a particular solution of an ODE? If we just check that $f'(x_{eq}) = 0$, how do we know which solutions of the ODE this makes sense for?

Comment: But $x(t)=0$ is also a solution, and that is all that is required to characterize this as stationary point. You seem to be concentrated on solutions, but equilibrium points are a property of the phase space, not of particular solutions.